# How can I format 8 subfigures to have a single legend to the right of the page?

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats, subcaption

My code produces a figure which looks like this:
[image]

How can I make it look like this:

[image]

(which I have produced using paint.)

**The code**

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{2}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{4}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{5}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{6}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.05\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=0.35\textheight]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/legend}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{7}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{8}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures}\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the subfigures in a `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{1}\label{1}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{2}\label{2}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{3}\label{3}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{4}\label{4}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{5}\label{5}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{6}\label{6}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{7}\label{7}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{8}\label{8}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Global caption}\label{global}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is just for showing the placement with respect to the text block.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to maintain the sizes of the images, but change the spacing.  Note that the `minipage` changes the value of `\textwidth`, hence the use of `\mywidth`.

Since the actual images have a lot of white space at the top, the subcaptions should be positioned appropriately.

Note that the legend is centered relative to the images AND their captions.  That can be fixed, but you need to measure the height of the images sans captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% dubugging tool
\newlength{\mywidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \mywidth=0.45\textwidth
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{2}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

  \begin{minipage}[c]{.925\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{3}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{4}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{5}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{6}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=0.35\textheight,width=0.05\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/legend}}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{7}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{8}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

  \caption{Pictures}\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version computes the widths to place a `\columnsep` gap between the images and use the natural width of the legend.  Of course, it looks awful in demo mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% dubugging tool
\newlength{\mywidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[height=0.35\textheight]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/legend}}%
  \setlength{\mywidth}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-\columnsep-0.5\wd0}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{2}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

  \begin{minipage}[c]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd0}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{3}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{4}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{5}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{6}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \raisebox{-0.5\ht0}{\usebox0}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{7}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mywidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./dct_for_publication_no_legend/ACTA2}
        \caption{8}
        %\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

  \caption{Pictures}\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```